# reference-request tag is missing

Tags: support, on-topic-definition, resource-questions

Why there is no `reference-request` tag?

I want to ask where can I read about a certain topic.

Are questions like this offtopic?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Reference requests are off topic. From our ["What topics can I ask about here?"](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) help article:

> Some questions, even if they appear to fit into one of the above categories, may still be off-topic or a poor fit for this format:
>
> - [explaining, writing or debugging code](http://meta.programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/7864/why-are-implementation-and-debugging-questions-unwelcome-on-programmers-se)
> - [providing support for tools or products](http://meta.programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/8197/why-cant-i-ask-customer-service-related-questions-here)
> - **[finding or recommending products or services, including tools, libraries or packages, programming languages, books, scholarly papers, tutorials, articles, or blogs](http://meta.programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/6483/why-was-my-question-closed-or-down-voted/6487#6487)**
> - [career or education advice](http://meta.softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/8206/are-career-advice-questions-on-topic-here)
> - legal advice or aid

Answer (score 4):

[The Help Center](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) specifically defines this type of question as off-topic:

> Some questions, even if they appear to fit into one of the above categories, may still be off-topic or a poor fit for this format:
>
> ...
>
> [finding or recommending products or services, including tools, libraries or packages, programming languages, books, scholarly papers, tutorials, articles, or blogs](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6483/why-was-my-question-closed-or-down-voted/6487#6487)